# Yii2 - Making dropdown list from db structure not the the inserted data in db

Tags: forms, yii2, gii

I have a form page that one of the field is named `type` and it's `enum('lost', 'found')` and in this form, I want that field to be a dropdown list that only has these two options `lost` and `found`.
one of the suggested options was using this in **view**

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'type')->dropDownList(
            $items,
            ['prompt'=>'']
```

and this in the **controller**

```
$items = ArrayHelper::map(Ads::find()->all(), 'id', 'type');
```

but as you know it's just using the inserted data in the db and if I click on the dropdown list, it'll load all the lost and found options that are in the db.
Is  there any way to tell yii to use the db structure and rules instead of the datas?

I have to point out that in the model I couldn't find any rules that is indicating the enum part, Is it ok? Why is it like this?
 **I used Gii for creating these.**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['type', 'explanation', 'image', 'cost', 'province_id', 'address'], 'required'],
        [['type', 'explanation', 'image', 'address'], 'string'],
        [['cost'], 'integer'],
        [['province_id'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
        [['province_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Province::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['province_id' => 'name']],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When a filed type is enum and generate crud from gii, yii generate this kind of dropdown in your form automatically.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'type')->dropDownList([ 'lost' => 'Lost', 'found' => 'Found', ], ['prompt' => '']) ?>
```

In model its type is string:

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
              [['type'], 'string'],
```

Comment: it's not what gii has created , that's what I did for that. Gii created just as the normal way.like this:  `<?= $form->field($model, 'type') ?>`

Comment: are you sure field 'type' is enum datatype?

Comment: yeah, but as I said i don't get why in model there is nothing that is related to enum part. I've posted the rules in model.

Comment: @Amir, very strange, I will check.

Comment: I think there is no rule for enum in model

Comment: so if there is no rule for enum, then Gii can't create a dropdown list based on db structure?

Comment: @Amir I added type field in user table and generate a crud, I can see this dorpdown code: `<?= $form->field($model, 'type')->dropDownList([ 'lost' => 'Lost', 'found' => 'Found', ], ['prompt' => '']) ?>` generated by Gii.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The problem was with Gii

Comment: long story but I've installed a plugin named "merena farmework" that it made a php core warning. I just removed that plugin.